# the layer imported from csv I'm trying to add in qgis is in the middle of the ocean

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to add sampling points to a layer which was initially created. 
This layer is in Bangalore and the points I'm trying to add is in the middle of the ocean, but if I search for the points on the maps generally, the coordinates seem to be right. 
I've also tried changing the lat and long for x and y axis respectively. 
I've checked for the CRS systems also which are set to the same system.
Please help me identify the issue cause I fail to see where the error is.

Comment: Could you add some sample lat/long of your CSV file?

Comment: Do you have reprojection-on-the-fly turned on?  What is the CRS of your points?  What is the CRS of background map?  Can you show us a sample of the data?

Comment: Which ocean? Are they showing up in the Atlantic? If so, they're probably being seen be the software as being in a projected crs when they're really lat-lon.

Comment: Thank you, I figured the error was in the geographic reference systems.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are switching the coordinates. X is Longitude and Y is Latitude. You said:

> I've also tried changing the lat and long for x and y axis
>   respectively

You have to modify the axes as I mentioned earlier.